# Microsoft graph API: Accessing presences information via an Application scope

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to access user's presence off of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I've granted my AD app Presence.ReadWrite.All which is described as "Allows the app to read all presence information and write activity and availability of all users in the directory without a signed-in user. Presence information includes activity, availability, status note, calendar out-of-office message, time zone and location.
".

There seems to be a bit of a conflict between the docs and what the permission's name is - the docs seem to imply it doesn't work with an application scope, while the permission name/description seems to say it does.

The error i'm getting is `Forbidden`. This seems to be different from accessing a resource with insufficient permissions (which straight up says InsufficientPermissions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are clear that you can't do this with Application scope. That means even if the particular permission *seems* like it should work, it might be because it's used in that way for another endpoint. Notice that, for instance [setPresence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setpresence?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [clearPresence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-clearpresence?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) both support `Presence.ReadWrite.All`.

What's really crazy though is that neither [getPresence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (your endpoint) ***nor*** (get Presence for Multiple Users)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/cloudcommunications-getpresencesbyuserid?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http] support `Presence.*Read*Write.All` - there is no supported *read* scenario!

From what I can see, your best bet is to keep an eye on [this request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/graph-api-presence-should-support-application-permissions/idi-p/2276109) and to upvote it. Microsoft (Darrel Miller) is quite active there from last year - perhaps there's an update coming.

Comment: Yeah this is about where I got to as well, wasn't sure if I wasn't missing something obvious - feels weird that you can write but not read. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, as the other site comments say, it should just be Presense.Write.All - that's exactly what that naming convention is for. Looks like you'll need a Delegated user workaround, but upvote over there anyway, hopefully it will get changed.

Answer (score 0):

@Hristo Dimitrov

[getPresence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api with application permission is now working.check Darrel Miller latest [comment](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/graph-api-presence-should-support-application-permissions/idc-p/4014669/highlight/true#M2155)